# Draw a picture using gradient with a lot of points random color

Tags: ios, uiimage, gradient, quartz-2d, quartz-core

The task is to create an image that consists of gradient of a lot of points that represent different colors. For example it is not a problem to draw a gradient between to points, but near the line of these two points can be another point that have an effect changing gradient between these two points. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look into [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/index.html)... I have posted two examples below of Core Graphics gradient rendering.

---

## 1D Linear gradient with multiple colors

This method will create an image with a simple 1D linear gradient (from top to bottom) with a given array of colors, all evenly spaced. You can customise your own spacings by setting your own values in `gradLocs[]`.

```
-(UIImage*) gradientImageWithSize:(CGSize)size withColors:(NSArray*)colors {

    // Start context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSUInteger colorCount = [colors count];
    CGFloat gradLocs[colorCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < colorCount; i++) gradLocs[i] = i/colorCount; // Even spacing of colors.

    // Create a simple linear gradient with the colors provided.
    CGGradientRef grad = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, gradLocs);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Draw gradient with multiply blend mode over the source image
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, grad, CGPointZero, (CGPoint){0, size.height}, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(grad);

    // Grab resulting image from context
    UIImage* resultImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultImg;
}
```

### Usage:

```
NSArray* colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor purpleColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
[self gradientImageWithSize:(CGSize){500, 500} withColors:colors];
```

---

## 2D gradient with multiple colors

This method, while not a very accurate way of generating a 2D gradient, is definitely the easiest way through Core Graphics. The radius parameter defines how far away from the point that the color has influence. To do this I created a custom object to store the gradient information at a given point:

```
/// Defines a simple point for use in a gradient
@interface gradPoint : NSObject

/// The color at the given point
@property (nonatomic) UIColor* color;

/// The position of the point
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint point;

/// The radius of the point (how far the color will have influence)
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat radius;

@end

@implementation gradPoint

+(instancetype) pointWithColor:(UIColor*)color point:(CGPoint)point radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    gradPoint* p = [[self alloc] init];
    p.color = color;
    p.point = point;
    p.radius = radius;
    return p;
}

@end
```

The gradient generation method then takes a size and an array of these `gradPoint` objects.

```
-(UIImage*) gradient2DImageWithSize:(CGSize)size gradPointArray:(NSArray*)gradPoints {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0);

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(c, (CGRect){CGPointZero, size});

    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

    CGFloat gradLocs[] = {0, 1};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    for (gradPoint* point in gradPoints) {
        NSArray* colors = @[(id)point.color.CGColor, (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        CGGradientRef grad = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, gradLocs);
        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(c, grad, point.point, 0, point.point, point.radius, 0);
        CGGradientRelease(grad);
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIImage* i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return i;
}
```

### Usage:

```
CGFloat gradRadius = frame.size.height;

NSArray* gradPoints = @[
                   [gradPoint pointWithColor:[UIColor redColor] point:CGPointZero radius:gradRadius],
                   [gradPoint pointWithColor:[UIColor cyanColor] point:(CGPoint){0, frame.size.height} radius:gradRadius],
                   [gradPoint pointWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] point:(CGPoint){frame.size.height, 0} radius:gradRadius],
                   [gradPoint pointWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] point:(CGPoint){frame.size.height, frame.size.height} radius:gradRadius]
                   ];


UIImage* gradImage = [self gradient2DImageWithSize:(CGSize){gradRadius, gradRadius} gradPointArray:gradPoints];
```

This method works best with a **square** image, with the radius set to the height/width.

### Example Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but I am not sure how this method will work for example if we have 2 points: (100, 100) and (200, 200). We need 2 dimensions: x and y. And here as I can see we have  gradLocs that is one dimensional c array.

Comment: I've added a fairly quick Core Graphics method that will render a 2D gradient, although fairly inaccurately.

Comment: was the 2D gradient code helpful? Please be sure to accept the answer if it was :)